# Autofac interception configuration for generics

Tags: logging, autofac, interception

I'm trying to do some sort of interception by using Autofac. Currently I've some bll objects configured:

```
updater.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseBll<>))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest()
            .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(ActivityLogger));
updater.Register(c => new ActivityLogger());
```

I put Interception attribute on one of the classes:

```
[Intercept(typeof(ActivityLogger))]
public class MyClassBll : BaseBll<TModel>, IMyClassBll
```

Unfortunately, the Intercept method is not called when calling some methods from MyClassBll. If you have any ideas, how this might be fixed, please let me know.

For now I've found temp workaround:

```
updater.RegisterType<MyClassBll>().As<IMyClassBll>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
```

Comment: How are you resolving the type you want to observe?

Comment: For now I'm using Intercept attribute that I'm placing on classes I want to observe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Autofac has a bug with property injection, changing it to constructor injection solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include .EnableInterfaceInterceptors() or .EnableClassInterceptors() before the .InterceptedBy(). Take a look here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html

[UPDATE]

As requested, I provided a code sample, based on the posted code:

```
updater.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseBll<>))
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .InstancePerRequest()
  .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
  .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
  .InterceptedBy(typeof(ActivityLogger));
```

Comment: explain your answer with an example first and then refer links.

Comment: Sure @NickCoder, as you requested, I've  provided a code example